# Prettify() error using python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, urllib2

Code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page1 = urllib2.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_human_stampedes")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page1)

print(soup.prettify())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Trash\Crawler Try\try2.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(soup.prettify())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 8775: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 2.4s with exit code 1]
```

I can't seem to get the error. I am using Python 2.7.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a console as ASCII then during print, there is a conversion from unicode to ascii, and if there is character outside ASCII scope - exception is thrown.

But if console can accept unicode, then everything is correctly displayed.Try this command and run program again

> export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: I am using sublime text 2 . Where in code should I put this command.

Comment: import os  os.environ["LANG"]="en_US.UTF-8"... copy this below import urllib2

Comment: I get the following error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Trash\Crawler Try\try2.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(soup.prettify())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 8775: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 17.5s with exit code 1]